# What are the benefits of encoding multiple values in the upper/lower bits of an integer value?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have this unproven notion in my head that it can be beneficial to encode two or more related values inside one integer-based value type, and by reading the upper and lower bytes you can extract encoded values out from them.

For an easy example, imagine I have a large array of 32-bit unsigned integers. The upper 16 bits represent of each 32-bit integer represents `Data1`, and the lower 16 bits represent `Data2`.

Are there any benefits in encoding multiple smaller values in an integer compared to simply making a struct with these different values as individual fields?

Comment: How about an array of 16-bit integers instead?

Comment: c, c++ or c#? Pick one

Comment: @dbush I guess that's very valid approach. That could be a little confusing to other developers since say each two values are tied to one entity.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Okay, C# then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the situation, this is a valid approach. Consider 4 channel ARGB colour values. When each channel is 8 bits each, these colours are commonly stored in a 32 bit integer as 0xRRGGBBAA. Since colours are often in involved in performance-intensive graphics applications, this is a useful optimization.

In other cases, readability and developer-friendliness are usually more important than such low level optimization tricks. It is much easier to read, understand, and use structs of multiple values than deconstruct an integer.

In short, it depends.

EDIT:

I was under the impression that graphics hardware required colour to be passed as a single integer and thus storing them this way would save conversion time. This may be incorrect as I can't find any evidence to back this up. This practice may simply be a convention. I'd appreciate any more knowledgeable people to chime in.

A potential optimization use-case is when values do not fit cleanly into the size of existing data types. Consider wanting to store a 6-bit value. By storing 4 of these values in a single 24-bit value, 8 bits of memory are saved versus storing each 6-bit value inside a typical 8-bit value.

A reason to favour structs over packing integers is issues of portability. Machines being little-endian versus big-endian will affect how a multi-byte value is stored in memory. If the program depends on a certain order of bytes in a multi-byte value, the order could be flipped on a different machine.

In general, my personal feeling is that unless there is a specific reason to pack values into a single value, like memory constraints, favour structs.

Comment: How is this an optimization? How is it faster for the CPU to encode multiple values as one? Isn't the bit-manpulation slower than reading a value?

Comment: @AquaGeneral I edited my answer elaborating some.

Comment: Sometimes manipulations on tuples can be done with instructions in a SIMD fashion.  For colors, for example, you might want to prenormalize RGB by multiplying each by the alpha value.  Or you might want to increase gain on colors with a clamp.  There can be single machine instructions for each of these.  A compiler may or may not be able to discover them if you treat the 4 channels as a tuple with separate operations.  (Or it might!)